# reponse from webapi with byte array get as null

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-web-api, response, restsharp

I have a response as below

```
public class Getfile_response
{
  public string file_name { get; set; }
  public byte[] file { get; set; }
}
```

And a call to web api as follows

```
var request = new RestRequest("API/Eprocess/GetMEREResponse", Method.POST);
var response = ExecuteRequest<Getfile_response>(request, requestData);
```

and this call reach the webapi and it assign value as below

```
resp.file_name = "test.xml";

byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\XMLFiles\response_files\test.xml");
resp.file = fileBytes;

return resp;
```

it is assigning values but when it reach the response it show as null. If I comment the byte array then the response will show with file_name. What is missing

Comment: What's a `RestRequest`?

Comment: @ErikPhilips It's from RestSharp: http://restsharp.org/

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to get a byte array back? Null mostly means that file was either not set, has the wrong data type, or the names mismatch

Comment: ya, suppose to be byte array. We are assigning the same and file exist.While debugging from webapi it is assigning and returning..im trying now below answer

Comment: Are you not forgetting to download data? `var fileBytes =restClient.DownloadData(request);`

Answer (score 0):

You should return your file as a base64 string instead of a byte[] in your return class

```
public string file { get; set; }
```

And change your controller

```
resp.file_name = "test.xml";

byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\XMLFiles\response_files\test.xml");
resp.file = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);

return resp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The response is retrieved fine by `RestClient` and `IRestResponse<T>.Data` returns `null` just because `RestSharp` serializer couldn't handle response format. You can use `Json.NET` and deserialize response content by yourself to avoid this problem

```
var response = ExecuteRequest(request, requestData);
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Getfile_response>(response.Content)
```